# Communicating using receiver node in webots

Tags: robotics, receiver, webots, emitter

I want to implement an emitter robot and a receiver robot in webots. I have written following code.

```
#include <webots/robot.h>
#include <webots/receiver.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TIME_STEP 64

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /* necessary to initialize webots stuff */
  wb_robot_init();
  WbDeviceTag rx = wb_robot_get_device("receiver");
  wb_receiver_enable(rx, 64);
  printf("Receiver sampling period: %d",wb_receiver_get_sampling_period(rx));
  
  while (wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) != -1) {
    
    if (wb_receiver_get_queue_length(rx) > 0) {
      const char *message = wb_receiver_get_data(rx);
      const double *dir = wb_receiver_get_emitter_direction(rx);
      double signal = wb_receiver_get_signal_strength(rx);
      printf("received: %s (signal=%g, dir=[%g %g %g])\n",
             message, signal, dir[0], dir[1], dir[2]);
      wb_receiver_next_packet(rx);
    }
  };

  /* Enter your cleanup code here */

  /* This is necessary to cleanup webots resources */
  wb_robot_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles successfully. But when I execute it, it generate following result,

Error: wb_receiver_enable(): invalid device tag.
Error: wb_receiver_get_sampling_period(): invalid device tag.

How can I fix this error?

I want to receive the message emitted by emitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows up because there is no device named `"receiver"` in your `Robot` node. What kind of robot are using? If it is a `Robot` node defined in the world file (`.wbt`), you should add to the `children` list of your `Robot` node a `Receiver` node named `"receiver"` (which is the default name). If you are using a PROTO-based robot, like `E-Puck` or `Nao`, you should check whether the proto file already contains a `Receiver` node and use its `name` instead of `"receiver"`. If it doesn't contain any `Receiver` node, you should be able to add a `Receiver` node in some `extensionSlot` of the robot.

The very same principle applies to the `Emitter` node as well.